# Not able to access the connectionString

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a solution in which there are two projects, one the main project and the other classLibery project for Entity Framework(Since I'm not able to create an ADO.Net Data Entity Model in ASP.Net core project) I added the reference of the ClassLibery project in the main project and created an object  of it and I am able to access all the properties of the Entity model. But when I run the code I get an Exception

> "InvalidOperationException: No connection string named
>   'DefaultConnection' could be found in the application config file.
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()"

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SchoolMate.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I have the same connection string in both the projects.
I tried the solutions given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084916/no-connection-string-named-could-be-found-in-the-application-config-file) and many other links but none could help.

My HomeController, i get the exception inside the Index method at

```
var i = Model1Entities.Products.Where(x => x.ProductId==1);
```

this is my complete home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    Entities Model1Entities;
    public HomeController()
    {
        Model1Entities = new Entities();
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var i = Model1Entities.Products.Where(x => x.ProductId==1);
        return View();
    }
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to find out the solution. we need more details. can u share code?

Comment: which part of the code do you need??

Comment: where you get an error? where you are trying to access the connection string

Comment: Share your `Model1Entities` class code.

Comment: `.net core` reads connection string from `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

In DBContext class :

```
public partial class DefaultConnectionMapClass : DbContext
    {
        public DefaultConnectionMapClass(): base("name=DefaultConnection")
        {
            // Your code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but couldn't resolve the issue.